# How to set up a menu icon in Joomla 3?

Tags: component, development, menu

I'm following a tutorial for adding a menu icon (2.5) to the backend. That didn't work. So I tried this (3.x): http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Adding_decorations_to_the_backend#helloworld.xml

That didn't work either. So I tried to inspect what's going on in chrome element inspector. My component is showing the below:

```
<a class="menu-com_component_16x16" href="index.php?option=com_component">Component Management</a>
```

"com_component_16x16.png" is my icon name. I checked that it is installed in the media/com_component/images/ folder correctly. What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answered my own question shortly after I wrote it. It was to do with the template. For some reason, the default ISIS template disables the icon view. If you are experiencing this problem, go to administrator/templates/isis/css/template.css and comment out the below:

```
/*.nav-collapse .nav li a,
.dropdown-menu a {
    background-image: none;
}*/
```